# python3.4 socket server receive image

Tags: android, image, sockets, python-3.4

I am trying to receive an image from Android to PC using socket in Python 3.4. My server code is as follows:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
address = ("10.0.0.22", 5000)
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except (socket.error, msg):
    print ('Failed to create socket.Error code:' + str(msg[0]) + ', Error    message: ' + msg[1])
sys.exit()
print ('Socket Created')
s.bind(address)
s.listen(5)

while True:
    (client, addr) = s.accept()
    print ('got connected from', client,addr)
    buf = b''
    while len(buf)<4:
        buf += client.recv(4-len(buf))
    size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)
    print ("receiving %s bytes" % size)

    with open('tst.jpg', 'wb') as img:
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print (data)
            if not data:
                break
            img.write(data)
    img.close()
print ('received, yay!')
client.close()
```

But it returns me a tst.jpg is  4 bytes less than my Android image.And I cannot open the image.

Here is my Android code:

```
FileOutputStream fop;
Socket socket;
try {
    fop=new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/dd.jpg");
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fop);
    fop.close();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    InetAddress serverAdd = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.22");
    SocketAddress sc_add = new InetSocketAddress(serverAdd,5000);
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(sc_add,2000);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python server expects first four bytes indicating the length of the file that follows.

Your android code does not send the four bytes of an integer containing the length of your bytes array.

So send first the four bytes of such an integer.

```
 int size = bytes.length;
```

Comment: You can as well send four bytes with value 0 first as the python code does not use it other than just logging it.

Comment: I have one more question.Why server write image so slow.How can I revise it?Thank you.

Comment: I cannot see how fast all goes. And if you don't tell i we will never know.